# Turn on or turned on?

Tags: sentence-construction

I am confused about "turn on" or "turned on" when submitting a maintenance request.

Is it correct to say this and why?

> The kitchen faucet keeps leaking when turned on?

Comment: Are you saying you're not sure whether it should be *keeps leaking when **turned** on* or *keeps leaking when **turn** on*?

Comment: It's enough to say, "The kitchen faucet is leaking" or "The kitchen faucet is dripping."

Answer (score 2):

"When turn on" is not grammatical: "when" needs to be followed by one of

- a full finite clause, including subject (eg *when it is turned on*)
- a participial clause, active (eg *when turning the tap on*) or passive (*when turned on*)
- an infinitive clause with "to" (*when to turn the tap on*) - this construction is different from the others, as it behaves as a noun phrase, eg *I know when to turn the tap on.*)

but it can't be followed by a bare infinitive clause (eg **when turn on*)